# Setting default value to h: selectOneMenu on button click

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, selectonemenu

I am displaying a output panel on button click, it has an selectonemenu item, by default value 1 is selected, when i change some value and click CANCEL button and reopen output panel, the last selected value is getting displayed. is there any way to display default value "1"... thanks in advance

```
<a4j: outputPanel id="new"> 

<h:selectOneMenu id="menuID" value="#{myController.count}" immediate="true"> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="1" itemValue="1" /> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="2" itemValue="2" /> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="3" itemValue="3" /> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="4" itemValue="4" /> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="5" itemValue="5" /> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="6" itemValue="6" /> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="7" itemValue="7" /> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="8" itemValue="8" /> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="9" itemValue="9" /> 
<f:selectItem itemLabel="10" itemValue="10" /> 
</h:selectOneMenu></td> 

<div id="popActionButtons"> 
<h:commandLink value="cancel" onclick="return closePoUpWindow(this);" /> 

<c1:ajaxCommandButton id="save" title="Save" 
onclick="return vailidatesav();" 
value="save" validationType="required" 
eventType="click" styleClass="inputButton" /></div> 
</div> 
</a4j: outputPanel>
```

Comment: Are you using some JS/Server side function for 'Cancel' button ?

Comment: No, I am just closing the pop-up,when CANCEL is clicked, here is the code
<h:commandLinkvalue="CANCEL" onclick="return closePoUpWindow(this);" />

Comment: Can you update your question with the above statement. Also share the code present in `closePoUpWindow()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just reset the "#{myController.count}" on panel opening? The problem is you put immediate="true"  on selectOneMenu, so on the clicking cancel button the form is submitted and all processes like validation, conversion, update model occur in "apply request values" phase. That's why you see the last value. So either you remove immediate="true"  from selectOneMenu and put it on cancel button, or must reset "#{myController.count}" on the button click, which opens the panel.

Answer (score 0):

check the below cases for the problem

1.I think you are using `<t:savestate>` to this variable **count**.. If that is the case please remove.
 2. Check the constructor of the bean  weather u r setting any value for this variable **count**.

if above are not the case you better use java script I suggest

1. onload of page set the default value to the dropdown.
2. Use **onclick** event to cancel button and call the java function to set the drop box value to 1..